# MultiValueDictKeyError for django image File upload

Tags: python, file-upload, django-forms, django-views

I have spent a LOT of time trying to resolve this- Read Django docs, consulted forms but not got anything satisfactory. So please be patient here with me.
I am trying to do an upload of an Image file here from my html template.
This is my html form

```
<form id="tryOnPageForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/dummy/{{frame.slug}}/">
{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="file" name="uploadFromPC" id="uploadFromPC" class="myButton" title="Upload From PC" value= "Upload from PC" onchange="uploadPC()" style="float:left;">
 <input type="submit" id="Submit" class="myButton" value= "Done" style="display:none"><br><br>

 </form>
```

The file upload happens properly an d I am able to see the uploaded image file in the HTML.

In my `views.py`,

```
def upload_image(request, frameslug):

frame= v.objects.get(slug=frameslug)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    print "FILES", request.FILES
    if form.is_multipart():
        save_file(request.FILES['image'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect('Successful')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Invalid image')
else:
    form = ImageUploadForm()
return render_to_response('dummy.html', {'form': form})


def save_file(file, path=''):
    ''' Little helper to save a file
    '''
    filename = file._get_name()
    fd = open('%s/%s' % (MEDIA_ROOT, str(path) + str(filename)), 'wb')
    for chunk in file.chunks():
        fd.write(chunk)
    fd.close()
```

and in my `forms.py`,

```
from django import forms
class ImageUploadForm(forms.Form):   
image = forms.ImageField(label='Select a file', help_text='max. 20 megabytes')
```

When I run my code I get this error

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /dummy/fr1234/
```

The print statement in my from my view.py shows this

```
FILES <MultiValueDict: {u'uploadFromPC': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: model4.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

and this is the traceback

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\Work-Backup\LiClipse Workspace\vTryON_DJango_Integration\vTryON\views.py" in upload_image
  189.             save_file(request.FILES['image'])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  301.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /dummy/fr1234/
Exception Value: "'image'"
```

I am aware that the enctype should be `multipart/form-data` since I have read it in tutorials. ALso, i have not used any field in my models.py to store the uploaded image.Instead I want to directly save it to thr MEDIA_URL location.Might that be an issue?
Please help. This has held me up for a long time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to solve this(after spending a lot of time and with some help from my friends...)

I think the error

`Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /dummy/fr1234/
Exception Value: "'image'"`

was coming because `request.FILES` was unable to get the uploaded image from the user input, the reason being that the name of the user input file that I provided was wrong!!

It should have been `request.FILES['uploadFromPC']` instead of `request.FILES['image']`  because that is the name that I had kept in my HTML.

```
<input type="file" name="uploadFromPC" id="uploadFromPC" class="myButton" title="Upload From PC" value= "Upload from PC" onchange="uploadPC()" style="float:left;">
```

That was a stupid error and a lot of time wasted to fix it..  :(

.. but ya, good learning.

I hope this helps somebody else who is trying to do something similar. Although, I would like it if somebody can explain to me the use of `forms.py` here.
Is it possible to do an user upload without `forms.py`?

Answer (score 2):

I found that the error occurs when you submit the form without selecting the file. when a file is not selected then the `input_name` in your case `image` is `u''`. this gives the error as the dictionary has no such key.
i tried to find a way to `try` and `except` error but there is no such exception in python `MultiValueDictKeyError`

Comment: i think u should try get mehod to take data and set by default value like request.POST.get('name','default_value')

Answer (score 0):

```
request.FILES['file1']
```

raises the multivaluedictkeyerror, so please check if you have the files under request.FILES like below -

```
if request.method == "POST" and 'file1' in request.FILES and 'file2' in request.FILES:
```

Don't use

```
if request.method == "POST" and request.FILES['file1']:
```

as it also raises error